# adsense doesn't show ads on my php page

Tags: javascript, php, adsense

I'm trying to integrate codes that provided by google, but i'm getting blank space with no error, I don't have any error in console java-script here is the code I use:

```
<script async   src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- bann vertical -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-......"
     data-ad-slot="95....."></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

i know there is already questions like this, but i cant find a solution for my problem any help would be appreciated

Comment: To get answers, you can to write to an AdSense specialists, if you are a website owner with over 300k monthly page views. See AdSense Support: https://www.google.com/adsense/start/get-started/contact-sales/#/

Answer (score 0):

If you adsense code above is generated, and you have no error in console then it is unlikely your code but your css hiding/masking it.

Check chrome dev tool into source and see if your  tag is visible

Comment: i dont know how can i check chrome dev tool into source?

Comment: @tamtoum1987 I see your code and where the two ad blocks are, it doesn't seems to be the issue. Have you check your adsense console if there were any issue? Have you just copied this code from another site of yours without validating this one? If all fails try the synchornised version instead of the async one. If the synchornised one failed as well then it is quite sure something with the adsense server other than problem from your side.

Comment: how can i know that my ads are validating  by google ? ok i will try synchronized one and i will see

Comment: I just tried on synchro and i m geting the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why Google serves "Blank ads" is because the language for a specific website is not supported by Google Adsense, but also for other reasons related to the design or scripts.

- Create an html page in English, in that page insert your original code from your adsense account.
- Go to your website where you want to place ads, edit the original code. Between two lines: `data-ad-client="ca-pub-......`"and `data-ad-slot=...`" insert new line: `data-page-url="http://www.yourdomain.com/your-html-page-english/"`

Your edited ad code will look like this:

```
<script async   src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- bann vertical -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-......"
     data-page-url="http://www.yourdomain.com/your-html-page-english/
     data-ad-slot="95....."></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: I just do like you said but i m still having blank

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
....
This is the body of your page.

<script async   src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- bann vertical -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-..."
     data-page-url="http://exams-english.com/index.html/
     data-ad-slot="7.."></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

Comment: Your "exams-english,com.html" does not contain enything. Ad some text (english), images. I sugest you to download a free html template then add some content. Google does not serve ads in blank pages. If you can see ads in test template, use ad code for your website in the format described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling and Ad-Blocking extensions in your browser.

Comment: already done, i tell that " I don't have any error in console java-script"